# Software to Display RFID information on Windows

Tags: windows, gratis

I have a [Reiner SCT cyberJack RFID Standard (German website)](http://www.reiner-sct.com/produkte/chipkartenleser/cyberJack_RFID_standard.html?pEl=5) device which should be able to read RFID cards.

[image: RFID Reader]

And since RFID becomes more and more popular, I also own a few RFID cards or chips. Since I'm interested in technology, I'd just like to know some of the details of those RFID cards. Therefore, I'm looking for a software

- for Windows (7 SP1 x64)
- that displays some internal data of the RFID card
- works with the Reiner SCT reader
- is gratis/free

It doesn't matter whether it's GUI or command line.